# Android update apk programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have an app on my phone. I was tried to call intent and install new version of apk. I've got error like that "There was a problem parsing the package". If I delete apk from my phone and install apk manually it works fine. What is the problem?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "ingfilm.apk"));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJHOr.jpg)

Comment: If the originally installed app was installed using development tools (like Android Studio) but the update package was created using a different method (e.g., build APK) then the signatures would be different and that would case the error.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me as:

```
intent.setDataAndType(
    Uri.parse("file://" + context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + apk_file),
    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

the key difference might be the `.getAbsolutePath()` part.

Comment: Editing an answer other than to make the layout or wording better, is not what we do on Stackoverflow. Instead, you'd make a suggestion in the comments and let the original author of the answer make the change.